# C++ avoid warning on non-used code parts

Tags: c++, warnings

I would like to use a code part in a complex system which is equivalent with the following:

```
static constexpr int abits = 13;
static constexpr int bbits = 10;

...

int atob(int a) {
    if ( abits == bbits ) return a;
    else if ( abits > bbits ) return a >> (abits-bbits);
    else return a << (bbits-abits);
}
```

`abits` and `bbits` may change over time (in compile time of course). There is always only a single line compiled in the final code, even in debug mode. However, I get a warning message on shifting by a negative value.

I use GCC 7.3.0, and do not want to avoid all warnings on negative shift values. I would like to get rid of warnings on codes which are not used at all. However, I did not find a switch for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`constexpr if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If) to branch at compile time if your condition is a `constexpr`.

```
static constexpr int abits = 13;
static constexpr int bbits = 10;

int atob(int a) {
    if constexpr ( abits == bbits ) return a;
    else if constexpr ( abits > bbits ) return a >> (abits-bbits);
    else  return a << (bbits-abits);
}
```

`constexpr if` is a c++17 feature which is available on gcc 7.3.0 with the `-std=c++17` flag.

Edit : A c++14 solution can use [`std::enable_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if). The trick is to provide an overload for the three cases and only enable the one that is applicable.

```
static constexpr int abits = 13;
static constexpr int bbits = 10;

#include <type_traits>

template<int I>
std::enable_if_t<I == 0, int> 
atob_impl(int a) {
    return a;
}

template<int I>
std::enable_if_t<(I > 0), int> 
atob_impl(int a) {
    return a >> (abits-bbits);
}

template<int I>
std::enable_if_t<(I < 0), int> 
atob_impl(int a) {
    return a << (bbits-abits);
}

int atob(int a) {
    return atob_impl<abits - bbits>(a);
}
```

Comment: That solved my problem. However, I am curious, whether there is a general solution to similar problems for warning supression (maybe all these problems can be solved in language level). E.g. using C++14 only.

Comment: @FERcsI There usually is a way. In this case, you could use `std::max(0, bbits-abits)` (I updated my answer)

Comment: Thanks, that was in also my mind, but it is a bit weird looking for me.

Comment: @FERcsI I've updated my answer with a c++14 solution.

Comment: THX. Impressive solution :)

Comment: @FERcsI [You don't need to say "thanks" in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126184/218012). To say "thanks" to an answerer, just to upvote the answer. If the answer solved your problem, accepting it is the right response (click on the little checkmark). See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using GCC 7.3.0, which supports C++17 with `-std=c++17`, you can silence this warning by using `if constexpr`:

```
int atob(int a) {
    if constexpr ( abits == bbits ) return a;
    else if constexpr ( abits > bbits ) return a >> (abits-bbits);
    else return a << (bbits-abits);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/g/EdQ32T)

---

In general, there's often a way to suppress warnings in code (that is, without `#pragma`s to disable the warning). Unused variable warnings can be suppressed by `(void)variable;`, assignments in `if` can be suppressed by adding extra parens (`if ((thing = value))`), etc.

In this case, you can suppress the warning by using [`std::max`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max):

```
else return a << std::max(0, bbits-abits);
```

Since `bbits` and `abits` are `constexpr`, the compiler will do constant folding on the `std::max` call and produce a direct result (assuming compiled with optimizations).

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/g/EqmKXK)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the classical C solution is frowned upon for C++, but it exists: you can use

```
#define abits 13
#define bbits 10

int atob(int a) {
#if abits == bbits
    return a;
#elif abits > bbits
    return a >> (abits-bbits);
#else
    return a << (bbits-abits);
#endif
}
```